# Why FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED doesn't work concurrently in my Flask app?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, psycopg2

It appears that `SKIP LOCKED` doesn't work as expected with concurrent connections for the following query:

```
UPDATE note_queue
SET seq_number = seq_number + 1, rand = random()
WHERE id IN (
SELECT id
FROM note_queue
ORDER BY seq_number, rand
FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
LIMIT 1
)
RETURNING id;
```

Full code: https://gist.github.com/RicoElectrico/0fef9d274dfd8e0d6f19a69805170d92

Table definitions:

```
               Table "public.note_queue"
   Column   |  Type  | Collation | Nullable | Default  
------------+--------+-----------+----------+----------
 id         | bigint |           |          | 
 seq_number | bigint |           |          | 0
 rand       | real   |           |          | random()
Indexes:
    "idx_note_queue" btree (seq_number, rand)
    "idx_note_queue_id" btree (id)
```

After running Apache Bench with 100 concurrent connections I see this:

```
changesets=# select seq_number, count(*) from note_queue group by seq_number;
 seq_number | count  
------------+--------
          0 | 499832
          1 |   4073
          2 |    266
          3 |      3
(4 rows)
```

Which is not what I expected, there should be only two distinct values of seq_number at one time.

What am I doing wrong?

What does help is using only a single connection guarded by `threading.Lock()`.

Comment: 1) What are you trying to accomplish? 2) Not sure how `... ORDER BY seq_number, rand...` is helping? 3) At [Locking clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE)  read complete section: *Caution It is possible for a SELECT command running at the READ COMMITTED transaction isolation level and using ORDER BY and a locking clause to return rows out of order. ...*

Comment: 1) This is a queue which serves each item randomly, but will serve any particular item next time only after all items have been served.
2) rand is pre-computed because otherwise Postgresql is really, really slow...
3) So this kills the idea, it seems. I can live with the simpler single-threaded threading.Lock() variant, though. It's performant enough, north of 180 rps on my laptop-in-a-closet server.